# Grabbing the input of 3 fields and putting them into an array which would then be used for an API call

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm working on a project that requires me to grab user input from 3 fields. After submission, these would then be placed into an array which could be used to generate an API call based of these parameters.

```html
<h2>ENTER YOUR INGREDIENTS</h2>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right">
    <form class="search-form">
        <input type="text" class="field" id = "form1" placeholder="First Ingredient">
        <input type="text" class="field" id = "form2" placeholder="Second Ingredient">
        <input type="text" class="field" id = "form3" placeholder="Third Ingredient">
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is the HTMl - currently im stuck on actually getting the forms to all submit at once at be placed into an array - i have little JS to show as i've been stuck.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is an error in your HTML, it should be:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Search"></input>
```

or

```
<button id="btn">Search</button>
```

On to the Javascript

```
// grab the form elements
const ingredient1 = document.getElementById('form1');
const ingredient2 = document.getElementById('form2');
const ingredient3 = document.getElementById('form3');
const submitButton = document.getElementById('btn'); 
const ingredientsArray = [];

// a function that pushes the values to the array
function createIngredientsArray(){
    ingredientsArray.push(ingredient1.value);
    ingredientsArray.push(ingredient2.value);
    ingredientsArray.push(ingredient3.value);
    alert(ingredientsArray);
    }

// add eventlistener
submitButton.addEventListener('click',createIngredientsArray);
```

[Here is a copepen](https://codepen.io/andreasaanestad/pen/MWVgmQm)